# GM Commands: Where are they stored in AzerothCore?

Tags: azerothcore

I have ran into an issue while using a couple of **GM Commands** and I would like to see if I can fix it. I need to know where are the **GM Commands** are stored? Thank you in advance for any help...

Sincerely,

Tinywolf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All commands are scripts and you can find them in https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/src/server/scripts/Commands (/src/server/scripts/Commands) folder :)

They are also linked to the `command` table within thw world database